# Imagetools in tinyMCE gets stuck

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I am trying to use imagetools with tinyMCE
I am adding images to the editor without any issues, but when I try to edit the image (e.g change dimensions) the progress bar doesn't go away. It stays at the top of the editor with the text "Image uploading... 100%" in it.

The change I make is applied to the image and it is saved without any issues.
This message appears in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) 
at XMLHttpRequest.g.onload (tinymce.min.js?apiKey=MINKEY:17) 
g.onload @ tinymce.min.js?apiKey=MINKEY:17
```

For every change I make to the image (any image in the editor) there is another progress bar added to the top. Even after I save and reload the page, the progrss bar(s) are still there, untill I remove the image.

I load the tinyMCE core from their CDN, but the I have the same problem if i load it localy. Jquery is loaded through Google's hosted libraries and this problem occurs regardless of jQuery version.

Please help, I can't find a sollution to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Your code is expecting JSON content, however, it is receiving the `<` character at position 0, which is incorrect.

Comment: Do you know where in the plugin files this JSON-response is coming from?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.g.onload` (tinymce.min.js?apiKey=MINKEY in the line 17. In Google Chrome, press F12 and insepect the Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was the JSON returned by the jbimages plugin saying where the uploaded file is located. Problem solved by creating a proper JSON object with the correct location.